# Backfill a D3 bar chart with gray to show 100% vs. actual

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a gray fill in the background to show 100% with the actual percentage fill in the foreground, please see the image:

[Image of what I'm trying to do](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23726217/example.PNG)

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G7su8/)

```
        //load the status'
        var theStatus = svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", function (d) { return (d.status); })
                .attr("width", 0)
                .attr("height", 20);

        //animate the status
        theStatus.transition()
            .attr("width", function (d) { return xBarScale(d.percent); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return yBarScale(d.id)-10; })
            .duration(animationDur2);

    });
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by appending another set of rectangles with grey fill and constant width:

```
svg.selectAll(".background")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "background")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return yBarScale(d.id)-10; })
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", 20);
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G7su8/1/).